# Find the range of values of $p$ if $(\cos p -1)x^{2}+(\cos p)x+\sin p =0$ has real roots in the variable $x$.

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Find the range of values of $p$ if $(\cos p -1)x^{2}+(\cos p)x+\sin p =0$ has real roots in the variable $x$. Restrict the values of $p$ in $[0,2\pi]$.

The given equation has real roots if: $$\cos^2 p \geq 4\sin p (\cos p -1)$$ and we now need to find the range of values of $p$. I have tried manipulating the inequality but have not been able to find the range of $p$. Any suggestions? Also are their any other methods other than using the inequality?

Thanks...

Comment: you could have checked some random values of $p$ to get some idea.... have you tried something like that?

Comment: It is not very pretty, but it can be done! See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos^2+p+%3D+4sin%28p%29+%28cos%28p%29+-1%29) to find the endpoints of the intervals for which the inequality holds.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, I didn't put in values. I thought a direct proof could be obtained.(I don't know the proof as such) Anyways, $\pi$ and $\pi /2$ satisfy the inequality..

Comment: I have suggested what i would do when i do not find a proof immediately... I would roam around the equation putting some values hoping to see a pattern...

Comment: According to Mathematica, if $\cos^2 p = 4\sin p (\cos p - 1)$ then $17x^4 - 32x^3 + 32x - 16 = 0$ when $x = \cos p$, though I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Square $x^2= \pm4\sqrt{1-x^2}(x-1)$. Doesn't help much though.

Comment: @Macavity, Oh, right.  And sure it does.  $17x^4 - 32x^3 + 32x - 16 = 0$ can be solved explicitly for $x$, and then we just take $\arccos$ of that.

Comment: question edited.. Values of p restricted to $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Wrong solutions : https://edurev.in/question/542709/The-equation--cos-p-ndash-1-x2-cos-p--x--sin-p--0-    https://brainly.in/question/95234

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comments, the values of $p$ for which a real root(s) exist(s) isn't very "clean", but there is a cyclical range within which it holds. A good way to approximate these intervals is to graph the right-hand side and the left-hand side to obtain the points at which the equality holds, to determine the intervals' endpoints:

[image]

[image]

These points of intersection are given by:

Lower bound: [image]

Upperbound [image]

Comment: are the red dots on your graph some multiples of $\pi$?(not necessarily integral multiples)

Comment: See the values of $p$ posted above. The intervals are periodic.

Comment: Tell me something, why doesn't this innocent looking inequality have simple looking solutions? And is there no **formal** proof?

Comment: The formal proof is in finding the bounds within which the inequality holds. To do this, we find where $\cos^2 x$ intersects $4\sin p(\cos p -1)$, i.e., finding where $\cos^2 x = 4\sin p(\cos p -1).$ By brute force, to solve the equality, we obtain the values of $p$ posted above. Every one of these points, $\cos^2 x$ intersects $4\sin p(\cos p -1)$. All that remains is to determine the upper bounds and lower bounds of the intervals in question, and this involves evaluating the original inequality at values on either side of of the points of intersection.

Comment: This is a formal method that determines the values of $p$ for which the inequality holds; it involves solving the equation in $p$. This is not experimental. The graphs, on the other hand, provide sketches of what is happening on each side of the points of intersection, and allow us to *estimate* the values of $p$ for which the inequality holds.

Comment: Nothin can illustrate a problem but a nice plot. :+)

Comment: @amWhy, the answer given in my textbook is $p \in (0,\pi)$.. Is it correct??

Comment: @Apurv Are you sure that the posted problem was transposed correctly? If so, it may be that the textbook has a typo in the problem statement, since the values for $p$ satisfying the posted inequality are so messy (the inequality is correct to the given quadratic: so I'm thinking perhaps the quadratic posted above may have been a misprint.)

Comment: @amWhy, I am sure about the problem statement.. This question was asked in a competitive exam in the 90's..

Comment: Then yes, if we restrict the values of $p$ to $[0, 2\pi]$, it turns out that $p \in (0, \pi)$ satisfy the inequality: (see the first graph above). There are also other values of $p$ that satisfy the inequality, but that is because of the periodicity of the equation. So often, when solving for angles, we restrict solutions to $(0, 2\pi)$.